# post request error after TLS configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, tls1.2

I configured TLS(1.2 and 1.3) in my project and after that when i send GET request by postman everything is fine but if i send POST request the request is responded with 403 forbidden. How can i fix it?

SecurityConfig

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest()
                .requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

ServerConfig

```
@Configuration
public class ServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector getHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

Also yaml

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: password
    key-store-type: pkcs12
    key-alias: tomcat
    key-password: password
    protocol: TLS
    enabled: true
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3

  port: 8443
```

Comment: You enabled security so  you need to login and authenticate.

Comment: But the get request works fine if authentication is necessary why does it work?@M.Deinum

Comment: Actually it isn't authentication (my bad) it is the CSFR protection for post requests (that isn't needed for GET requests) that is blocking this. But you don't need that piece of configuration as Tomcat is already handling the SSL redirects.

Comment: Actually this is just a piece of the project i will specify the tls. For this reason, i first configure it in a custom way. But  how can i pass CSFR protection i did not understand why it joined the tls.@M.Deinum

Comment: It has nothing to do with TLS but with the fact you configured Spring Security which by default has CSRF protection enabled. Even if you remove the TLS stuff and leave the `@EnableWebMvc` you still have the same issue.

Comment: as deinum mentioned for test purpose try http.csrf().disable().. but careful

Comment: if i remove csrf protection are there any security leaks?@silentsudo @M. Deinum

Comment: Well you loose the protection which might open up a security leak in your application (if your application is stateful and using cookies that is).

Comment: The project is about providing an api for services so do you suggest it to me? Also you mentioned that above "you don't need that piece of configuration as Tomcat is already handling the SSL redirects". But the spring document suggests this two configuration on its website. @M.Deinum

Comment: You should really read the documentation. THe Spring Security one is only needed if you have both HTTP and HTTPS and you want to make sure certain URLs are only accessible through HTTPS. However in your case everything is HTTPS due to your tomcat configuration.